# Why does Pyinterval arithmetic fail with numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy, intervals

I work with Pyinterval and for some reason it doesn't go well with `numpy.float64`. Basically, whenever using a `numpy.float64` instead of the usual `float` in interval arithmetic, the intervals are being cast to numpy arrays.

The following example:

```
import interval as itv
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

ival = itv.interval([1,2])
cons = 2

print("interval 1: ",sqrt(cons)*ival)
print("interval 2: ",np.sqrt(cons)*ival)
```

prints:

> interval 1:  interval([1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903])
>
> interval 2:  [[ 1.41421356  2.82842712]]

and the types are accordingly. Basically, because I use `numpy` alot, my question is if I can somehow *force* it to never use its own float64 type, or if there is any other convenient solution aside from casting back after every numpy calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to `numpy` trying to cast the interval to something it knows how to multiply with. This evidently fails. Instead you can have the interval library do the conversion which seems to work in my tests:

#### Code:

```
ival = itv.interval([1, 2])
cons = 2

print("interval 1: ", ival * sqrt(cons))
print("interval 2: ", ival * np.sqrt(cons))
```

#### Results:

```
('interval 1: ', interval([1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903]))
('interval 2: ', interval([1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903]))
```

#### But Why?

Python implements the `*` operator with the `__mul__` dunder. The dunder which is called is the one for the left hand operand.  By putting the interval on the left side, you will use its conversion, instead of numpy's conversion.  Why `numpy` is unhappy, I do not currently know, but this seems to work.

Comment: a little dangerous (easy to mess up) but I'm very happy with this solution. Numpy and Pyinterval generally don't work well together (creating an array of intervals for example is also a little tedious) but at least in this case there's an easy way out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Time traveller is here. Stephen gave a very good answer, but I can answer his last "why" question. If python sees a product of two objects
`A*B` it tries to call `A.__mul__(B)` If, however, method `__mul__` of object `A` does not recognise class of object `B`, python tries to call `B.__rmul__(A)`. This is the method you need to implement in `interval` class for your second case.

See here for more details https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types